# Templatizing a parameter for a function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

I'm a beginner for programming and read an example codes, while I was learning about algorithm with C++.

```c++
template <size_t N>
void print(const std::array<int, N>& arr)
{
    for(auto element: arr)
    {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
}
```

Now I'm curious what the difference is for the templatizing like above and just passing the parameter like below.

```c++
void print(const std::array<int, size_t>& arr)
```

Does work they same? If yes, is there an advantage to write codes like the first example? If not same, could explain, what the difference between them is?

I guess there is no difference between them maybe..?

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does work they same?

No, the second snippet with `std::array<int, size_t>` won't even compile because the second template **parameter** of `std::array` is a **non-type** template parameter of type `std::size_t` and so it expects an **argument** of type `size_t`(or convertible to it).

Thus, `size_t` is not a valid template **argument** for the second non-type **parameter** and hence the second snippet won't compile.

```
//--------------vvvvvv------>invalid argument for a non-type parameter 
std::array<int, size_t>
```